# How to reference an img in p:graphicImage from the resource folder

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I have an image in the following path:

```
resources
\_____img
 \_______sites
  \_______reddit.png
```

I used this command line to reference it:

```
<p:graphicImage library="img" name="/sites/reddit.png"/>
```

but in the development console it says:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/RES_NOT_FOUND 404 ()
```

and the image is not rendered.

What's wrong?

Comment: Offtopic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: the `resources` folder is under WEB-INF, but it always fails to render the image. please help, that topic isn't helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kukeltje's suggested url ([What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)) is definitive resource to resolve this issue.

Based on that URL, I think the resources folder should not be under WEB-INF. It should have a structure as follows assuming that you are using a default maven project layout

```
src/main/webapp/resources
-------------------------/img
-----------------------------/sites
-----------------------------------/reddit.png
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
-----------------------/web.xml
```

Then the following JSF construct should work.

```
<p:graphicImage library="img" name="sites/reddit.png"/>
```

Comment: So just use a relative instead of absolute path ;-)